# Error 404 with all pages After Migrating my Magento to new server

Tags: magento-1.9, php

After Migrating my magento to new server. My Homepage is working and my admin page is also working. But all frontend pages will give 404 error. Note from initial server index.php has been removed. For example instead of **//mydomain.com/index.php/one-page.htm**l, we uses **mydomain.com/one-page.html.**

In the new server **mydomain.com/one-page.html**. is not working (Error 404) until you put index.php to it before it gives content on the page

Please what is the way out ?

Answer (score 2):

The two "usual suspects" are either your `.htaccess` file and/or configuration settings within Magento.

Assuming you have **mod_rewrite** installed, ensure the following is present in your `.htaccess` file:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then, from the Magento Admin Panel, browse to **System** » **Configuration**, and then then **General** » **Web**.

Check the **Use Web Server Rewrites** setting under the **Search Engines Optimisation** is selected to "Yes".

Ensure the **Base URL** field in both **Unsecure** and **Secure** fieldsets are configured correctly, *including* trailing slashes, for example:

> http://www.bluemwhitew.dev/
>
> https://www.bluemwhitew.dev/